# Java,Spark,Sql2o,H2: Could not acquire a connection from DataSource - IO Exception

Tags: java, apache-spark, h2, sql2o

I want to create an API using Java Maven, with Spark and H2 database and Sql2o library.

This is the full Error message:

> Exceptionorg.sql2o.Sql2oException: Could not acquire a connection from
>   DataSource - IO Exception: "java.io.IOException: The filename,
>   directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect";
>   "C:\Users\Claudiu/reviews.db:INIT=RUNSCRIPT from
>   'classpath:db/init.sql.mv.db" [90031-191]
>       [qtp1133151800-16] ERROR spark.webserver.MatcherFilter - 
>       ro.sparkmaven.exc.DaoException: Problem adding Course
>         at ro.sparkmaven.dao.Sql2oCourseDao.add(Sql2oCourseDao.java:28)
>         at ro.sparkmaven.App.lambda$0(App.java:37)
>         at ro.sparkmaven.App$$Lambda$1/1607460018.handle(Unknown Source)

This is the main class:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String connectionString= "jdbc:h2:~/reviews.db:INIT=RUNSCRIPT from 'classpath:db/init.sql";     
        Sql2o sql2o = new Sql2o(connectionString, "", "");
         CourseDao courseDao = new Sql2oCourseDao(sql2o);
         Gson gson = new Gson();

        post("/courses", "application/json", (req, res) -> {
            Course course = gson.fromJson(req.body(), Course.class);
            courseDao.add(course);
            res.status(201);
            res.type("application/json");
            return null;
        } , gson::toJson);

        get("/courses", "application/json", (req, res) -> courseDao.findAll(), gson::toJson);

        get("/courses/:id", "application/json", (req, res) -> {
            int id;
            id = Integer.parseInt(req.params("id"));
            //TO DO: What if this not found
            Course course = courseDao.findById(id);

            return null;
        });

        after((req,res)->{
            res.type("application/json");
        });
    }
}
```

This is init.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS courses (
   id int PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
   name VARCHAR,
   url VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reviews (
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
   course_id INTEGER,
   rating INTEGER,
   comment VARCHAR,
   FOREIGN KEY(course_id) REFERENCES public.courses(id)
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception message says, the URL is formatted incorrectly. Use a semicolon instead of a colon before `INIT`. The final `'` is missing as well. Try:

```
String connectionString = 
  "jdbc:h2:~/reviews.db;INIT=RUNSCRIPT from 'classpath:db/init.sql'";
```